# Java 'alternate' analog in swift

Tags: java, json, swift

I receive different json for the same java parameters.

In java we can use alternate and pass all values for the same parameter, how can I do the same in swift?

Or maybe some best practice for this case?

Thanks.

Json for example:

```
{

   id: 12345,
   name: "Some name"

}
```

```
{

   Id: 12345,
   Name: "Some name"

}
```

```
{

   someId: 12345,
   someName: "Some name"

}
```

[image]

Comment: _different json for the same java parameters_, please rephrase this without any Java references

Comment: Also, an example off the JSON would be useful.

Comment: @JeremyP added json examples

Comment: No there is nothing like that in swift, you need to implement a custom logic for handling different keys like this.